# Python Regex For Matching Multiword Names

Tags: python, regex

I want to match only alphabetic characters, i.e `a-z` or `A-Z`, which can also contain spaces. The intent is to match any multiword names like `'Vivek Jha'`. I expect the following Regex to work:

```
re.match(r'^[aA-zZ\s]+$', name)
```

It works for all the cases but also matches a word: `'Vivek_Jha'`

I do not want and *underscore* to be matched. How is this `_` getting matched.

I have worked on Regex in Perl and Tcl, but I think Python is doing something more that I can imagine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to match only alphabetic characters,which can also contain spaces just use :

```
r'^[a-zA-Z ]+$'
```

note that `aA-zZ` is wrong way for match letters you must use `a-z` for lowercase and `A-Z` for upper case .
Note :

The `\s` metacharacter is used to find a whitespace character.

A whitespace character can be:

```
A space character
A tab character
A carriage return character
A new line character
A vertical tab character
A form feed character
```

Answer (score 6):

`A-z` is capturing everything from ASCII character `A` to ASCII character `z`.  This includes the `_` character as well as many others.  For more information on this, you can view [Wikipedia's ASCII article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

To fix the problem, you need to do:

```
re.match(r'[a-zA-Z\s]+$', name)
```

This tells Python to only capture characters in the ASCII ranges `a-z` and `A-Z`.

Also, I removed the `^` because `re.match` matches from the start of the string by default.

Comment: Happy to have helped!  Please do not forget to accept an answer by clicking the check next to it.  Doing so lets people know that this problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Try `a-zA-Z` instead of `aA-zZ`.

a-z have nothing between them but letters, same for A-Z, but A-z have a lot of stuff in between... apparently including the underscore character.